# Inconsistent behavior of apply with operator.itemgetter v.s. applymap operator.itemgetter

Tags: python, pandas

May not be the best way of arrange data in real case, but it serves a good example:

```
In [16]:
import operator
In [17]:
DF=pd.DataFrame({'Val1':[[2013, 37722.322],[1998, 32323.232]],
                 'Val2':[[2013, 37722.322],[1998, 32323.232]]})
In [18]:
print DF
                Val1               Val2
0  [2013, 37722.322]  [2013, 37722.322]
1  [1998, 32323.232]  [1998, 32323.232]

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

`apply` gives wrong result

```
In [19]:
print DF.apply(operator.itemgetter(-1), axis=1)
   Val1       Val2
0  2013  37722.322
1  1998  32323.232

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

but `applymap` gives the right result!

```
In [20]:
print DF.applymap(operator.itemgetter(-1))
        Val1       Val2
0  37722.322  37722.322
1  32323.232  32323.232

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

Why could it happen?

Comment: apply is being passed an entire row which is a series of 2 elements which are lists; the last list is returned and coerced to a series. embedded lists as elements are not a good idea in general.

Comment: I agree, it is not a good way of storing data in real life. What is singularly interesting is that is first elements gets assigned to `Val1`. Now I see, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier to see what is happening if you use

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Val1':[[1, 2],[3, 4]],
                 'Val2':[[5, 6],[7, 8]]})

     Val1    Val2
0  [1, 2]  [5, 6]
1  [3, 4]  [7, 8]
```

`df.apply(operator.itemgetter(-1), axis=1)` calls `operator.itemgetter(-1)` on each row.

For example, on the first row, `operator.itemgetter(-1)` returns the last item, which is `[5, 6]`.
Since this value is iterable, its values are then assigned to the two columns `Val1` and `Val2`. So the result is

```
In [149]: df.apply(operator.itemgetter(-1), axis=1)
Out[149]: 
   Val1  Val2
0     5     6
1     7     8
```

In contrast, `applymap` operates on each cell in the DataFrame individually, so `operator.itemgetter(-1)` returns the last item from each cell.

```
In [150]: df.applymap(operator.itemgetter(-1))
Out[150]: 
   Val1  Val2
0     2     6
1     4     8
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what @unutbu and @jeff said, if there are 3 columns to start with:

```
In [26]:

print DF
                Val1               Val2               Val3
0  [2013, 37722.322]  [2014, 37722.322]  [2015, 37722.322]
1  [1997, 32323.232]  [1998, 32323.232]  [1999, 32323.232]

[2 rows x 3 columns]
In [27]:

print DF.apply(operator.itemgetter(-1), axis=1)
0    [2015, 37722.322]
1    [1999, 32323.232]
dtype: object
```

The resulting lists (having length of 2) can not be coerced to series of the length of 3, and the result is now a series of list.